# Show that this function is a contraction

Tags: operator-theory, tensor-products, compact-operators

Let $H$ denote a Hilbert space and $\mathcal{B}_1(H)$ denote the space of trace class operators on $H$. I believe that the following map is an isometry but I'm stuck on the proof that it's a contraction.

$$\Phi :H^* \widehat{\otimes} H \rightarrow \mathcal{B}_1(H), ~~\varphi \otimes f\mapsto\varphi f.$$

Here $\varphi f : H \rightarrow H$ is that trace class operator mapping $h \in H$ to $\varphi(h)f \in H$.

**Edit**: the norm on $H^* \otimes H$ is the projective one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Initially, I didn't know your norm was the projective one; maybe you could edit that into the question)*

---

First, $\Phi$ is injective. Indeed, if $\sum_{j=1}^n\varphi_j f_j=0$, we can do the following. Let $z_1,\ldots,z_m$ be a basis of $\text{span}\,\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$. So 
$$f_j=\sum_{k=1}^m\alpha_{jk}z_k,
%\ \ \ \ z_k=\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_{kj}f_j
$$
for appropriate coefficients. Then
$$
0=\sum_{j=1}^n\varphi_jf_j=\sum_{k=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_{jk}\varphi_j\right)\,z_k.
$$
As the $\{z_k\}$ are linearly independent, we get for each $k$
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_{jk}\varphi_j=0.
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n\varphi_j\otimes f_j=\sum_{k=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_{jk}\varphi_j\right)\otimes z_k=0.
$$

---

Now consider the norm, on $H^*\otimes H$, given by 
$$
\|x\|_0:=\|\Phi(x)\|_1.
$$
The linearity and injectivity of $\Phi$ make $\|\cdot\|_0$ a norm. And it is a cross norm: it is not hard to check that the one-norm of $\varphi f$ is $\|\varphi\|\,\|f\|$. Indeed, by the [Riesz Representation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem), the functional $\varphi$ is implemented by a vector $\varphi\in H$, i.e. $f\longmapsto \langle f,\varphi\rangle$. Let $T=\varphi f$. Then 
$$
\langle T^*h,k\rangle=\langle h,Tk\rangle=\overline{\langle k,\varphi\rangle}\,\langle h,f\rangle=\langle\,\langle h,f\rangle\,\varphi,k\rangle.
$$
So $T^*h=\langle h,f\rangle\,\varphi$ (that is, $(\varphi f)^*=f\varphi$; this is of course confunsing, and one usually uses the notation $f\otimes \varphi$ for this; but of course this notation would really cloud you question). Thus
$$
T^*Th=\langle Th,f\rangle\,\varphi=\|f\|^2\,\langle h,\varphi\rangle\,\varphi.
$$
One can check that $h\longmapsto \frac1{\|\varphi\|^2}\langle h,\varphi\rangle\,\varphi$ is a projection (i.e., selfadjoint and equal to its square). It follows that a (so "the") positive square root of $T^*T$ is 
$$
(T^*T)^{1/2}=\frac{\|f\|}{\|\varphi\|}\,\langle\cdot,\varphi\rangle\,\varphi. 
$$
So
$$
\|\varphi f\|_1=\text{Tr}((T^*T)^{1/2})=\|f\|\,\|\varphi\|\,\text{Tr}\,\left( \frac1{\|\varphi\|^2}\,\langle\cdot,\varphi\rangle\,\varphi\right)=\|f\|\,\|\varphi\|
$$
(a rank-one projection has trace one: this can be seen by using an orthonormal basis that includes $\varphi/\|\varphi\|$).

---

Now, as the projective norm is the largest cross norm on $H^*\otimes H$, we get 
$$
\|\phi(x)\|=\|x\|_0\leq \|x\|.
$$

Comment: Is it enough to show the result on those elements of the form $\varphi f$ ?
 Since the definition of the projective norm involves as an infimum over all possible representation, I thought one need to show that the result holds for all possible representations of an element of $H^*\otimes H$ as a finite sum of elementary tensors.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll delete for now.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to tensor products and I thought that the best way to indicate that the norm is the projective one is to use this notation: $\widehat{\otimes}$. It appears I was wrong.

Comment: No, you are not necessarily wrong; in some contexts, it is probably obvious. But it is certainly not canonical. Lots of symbols get put on top and to the side of the tensor symbol, and few (if any) are completely standard.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, could you say a bit more on how to check that the one-norm of $\varphi f$ is $\|\varphi\| \|f\|$ ?

Comment: Please see the edit.